# “Contribution to technical achievement” in Australia for the purpose of applying for a Lecturer position

Tags: computer-science, job-search, faculty-application, lecturer, australia

For the purpose of applying for a lecturer position in Australia in computer science, what is actually a "contribution to technical achievement"? This phrase occurs among the selection criteria but seems to me way too broad from a purely linguistic viewpoint. According to the text describing the selection criteria, a "contribution to technical achievement" is supposed to be separate from research experience, teaching experience, experience outside university, creative achievements, and professional contributions – they are measured separately.

Comment: I don't really see why you need three questions here. You should be able to combine them into a single question that asks what the different terms mean. This is especially true since they're all associated with the same issue, and anyone who wants to see one would probably want to see all three.

Comment: @aeismail ([One base at a time!](http://www.baseball-almanac.com/humor4.shtml)) Let's not mix the concepts. Some folks may be able to answer only one question - they should get separate votes for that. This is especially true since there have not been overwhelmingly many replies so far. Some other folks may be interested in only one term, not three, and should get appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that "technical achievement", within the context of computer science, is a reference to the production and development of computer software/hardware.  Hence, "contributions to technical achievement" is a cue to allow you to give information on any contributions you have made to the development of software/hardware/computing problems (e.g., a program you wrote or helped with).  There is probably going to be some overlap with "creative achievements".

Answer (score 0):

The job ad should list a contact.  You can ask them.

In my experience the selection criteria are not written very carefully.  So I would guess there is no precise answer to your question.